# Uninstall Windows on dual boot and install Lubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, lubuntu

This is a Gparted screenshot of my hard disk:

[image]

`/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sda5` are Windows and `/dev/sda7` has Ubuntu. I would like to uninstall the complete Windows partition and install Lubuntu on that.

I am scared that when I delete the Windows partition I will lose the grub and won't be able to load Ubunutu again.

Can you please guide me with safe steps to uninstall Windows and put Lubuntu there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what all the different windows partitions are, so I can't advise too much on what's in each one. But if you just wanted to delete/overwrite some partitions that aren't used for Lubuntu, you can use `gparted` and you should be able to edit/delete partitions that aren't used by your Lubuntu install. Running a live dvd/usb would let you edit any of the HD partitions, since it runs live off of the dvd/usb only.

Anytime you change/edit/delete hard disk partitions, there is a risk of data loss, so having a good backup of any important data **first** is always a good idea.

If you did lose your GRUB from deleting some partitions, you should keep a good live dvd/usb handy and you could always run the ["Boot Repair" utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), it should be able to re-install GRUB in case it was deleted.

Comment: Is it safe to remove the "recovery" and "system reserved" partitions? I guess the system reserved carries the GRUB.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with windows & not sure what those partitions are, but since they're NTFS I don't think they have anything to do with Ubuntu/Lubuntu or GRUB. It's possible GRUB would install some data to a NTFS partition (it has several "stages", one is usually in the MBR/GPT, another in some partition, and possibly a 3rd somewhere else?) but the "Boot Repair" utility *should* be able to fix any missing parts. Take a look in the partitions for anything named "grub"...